# Sql Data Adapter not fetching data

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following code:

```
string q = "SELECT 1";
using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand())
{
    sqlCommand.CommandText = q;
    sqlCommand.Connection = new SqlConnection(DataAccess.ConnectionString);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DataAccess.ConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
                sqlAdapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dt = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

been altering the code structure and try debug, but still couldn't get the data to be fetched every single time. The `dt` value in the end is always `{}`. The connection string is correct because been tried with the alternate solution with `SqlDataReader ExecuteReader()`, the data is fetched no problem.

Comment: tried the string `result = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();` it shows 1 too. but I don't  understand during debug everytime I hover over the `dt` it always show `{}`

Comment: @Amigo.. Well you need to click the small magnifier to see the data in the `DataTable` while debugging. Make sure you're not getting an exception that you're swallowing in the above code.

Comment: got it, thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me - I get a DataTable with one value `1`.

Add `string result = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();` after `Fill()`

To get the result during debugging, you have to click the magnifier icon after `Fill()` was called:

[image]